# Get the label of click check box

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

i have a page which generate check boxes dynamically and i have
the following event which fires every time a user click on any of the check boxes

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {

 });
```

My question is how can i get the text of the check box that has been trigger by the user? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking @CliffC query and changing it, This should work. Its an explicit query so you will always get the correct label

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {

 alert( $(this).parent().find("label[for=" + this.id +"]").text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution

```
$(':checkbox').click(function() {
   alert( $(this).parent().find("label").text());
 });
```

Comment: lol!.... there could be many label... if you did `.next()` or `.prev()`, it would be close... ;) but still, the OP is asking for a text on a checkbox, which is confusing.. ;)